# How to reduce the time complexity of this nested loop code in python

Tags: python, algorithm

Please help me reduce the time complexity of the nested loop in Python

df is a dataframe with say 3 columns, say name,  city and date for eg
rep data frame has the average/means based on 2 columns name and city  from df. I need to reattach the mean from rep to df

```
for i in range(0,len(rep)):
    for j in range(k,len(df)):
        if df["X"][j] == rep["X"][i]:
           df["Mean"][j] =  rep["Mean"][i]
       else:
           k=j
           break
```

Comment: Not sure why you're iterating over `len(rep)` and `len(df)` when they both appear to be dictionaries?

Comment: It's hard to tell what column 'X' represents here, but it sounds like what you're trying to do is insert the means from a keyed table (rep) into the df?  If so, why not use pd.merge to do so?  That would be a lot faster than looping.

Comment: also I see that your second loop is not necessary because you are only to to itterate once or twice. once if the values do not match and k does not change,  twice if they do and k will be one more.. I would suggest re-working this completely.

Comment: I just mentioned X - But X is combination of the 2 columns say age and name from the dataframe..

Comment: @Mark - Sorry still learning Python. Not sure what dictionarie are

Comment: @Kevin - the df dataframe has 3 columns for example Name,City,Date, other rep datafram has Name, City and Mean. So i want to get the Means by Name and city into df dataframe. Would either join or Merge work for this?

Comment: @Rob thanks.. I will try merge and join as suggested in the post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is something like:

```
df.set_index('X').join(rep.set_index('X'))
```

Setting as index the keys on which you are doing the join will make the process much faster. After you have done the join, you can filter the old mean (with the `drop` dataframe method), and the values that you don't want

Comment: Thanks what if X represents 2 columns - say Name and City df.set_index(["Name","City"]).join(rep.set_index(["Name","City"])) ??

Comment: new_df  = pd.merge(df, ref,  how='left', left_on=["Name","City"], right_on = ["Name","City"])

Comment: thanks so much @Nikaidoh..

Comment: New to Stack :).. Just did.. I will try it out later tonight.. If i have more questions, i will post it, is that ok?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not my job to do so. If I am still here I could help, but I cannot assure you that.  However it is better if you learn doing some research. It goes against Stackoverflow policy to do tutoring. We can help you by giving you some hints, that's all. Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Sure i understand..